# Are there any known gay wizards?

Tags: harry-potter

If yes, could they change their sexuality with the help of magic? Or, like muggles, they cannot change who they are attracted to?

Comment: Ummm. Dumbledore?

Comment: Dumbledore is gay. He was attracted to Grindelwald.

Comment: You're asking too many questions here. Now I'm gonna tell you what my scales tell me "1 at a time please".

Comment: As for the second part, I presume most gay wizards, like most gay Muggles, *don"t want to change their sexuality*. And JKR is hardly going to invent an "anti-gayness charm," thankfully.

Comment: Why would they want to? Would you want to change your own preferences? What your favourite colour is? What food you like? Your personality?

Comment: @Fabian - I'd quite like to change my food preferences. Some people seem to quite like salad, for example.

Comment: @Adamant Why wouldn't a gayness or anti-gayness charm be in demand? I mean, if there are love potions (that make people fall for people they wouldn't normally fall for) I'm sure there must be a market for things like these.

Comment: We already know that there are ways (potions) to change whom you’re attracted to—Ron would never have been attracted to Romilda Vane if it hadn’t been for the love potion. If a boy had sent that potion, Ron would essentially have effectively gone bisexual for the duration of the potion’s effect. Whether that’s actually changing someone’s sexuality is a very different—and **much** more complex—matter that I don’t think we can have any hope of answering here.

Comment: @JanusBahs - Ah, but would it have *worked*? We don't know whether "love" potions (a) work on people of the same sex or same gender, or (b) can make someone attracted to someone not within their sexual orientation. Expanding on (b), Fred and George said that the effectiveness of their potions depended on "the attractiveness of" the person using it. It's not much of a stretch to imagine that if they were used on someone to whom the administerer wasn't attractive at all (because the victim was a gay man and the administerer was female, say) that they'd be entirely ineffective.

Answer (score 5):

## Dumbledore, for one

To borrow a quote from [The Leaky Cauldron](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more/):

> **Did Dumbledore, who believed in the prevailing power of love, ever fall in love himself?**
>
> My truthful answer to you… I always thought of Dumbledore as gay. [ovation.] … Dumbledore fell in love with Grindelwald, and that that added to his horror when Grindelwald showed himself to be what he was. To an extent, do we say it excused Dumbledore a little more because falling in love can blind us to an extent? But, he met someone as brilliant as he was, and rather like Bellatrix he was very drawn to this brilliant person, and horribly, terribly let down by him. Yeah, that’s how i always saw Dumbledore. In fact, recently I was in a script read through for the sixth film, and they had Dumbledore saying a line to Harry early in the script saying I knew a girl once, whose hair… [laughter]. I had to write a little note in the margin and slide it along to the scriptwriter, “Dumbledore’s gay!” [laughter] If I’d known it would make you so happy, I would have announced it years ago!

For the second half of the question... **I very highly doubt it.** First off... Why would you want to change your sexuality?? You are who you are, and there's nothing to be ashamed of (unless you're a psychopath or sadist or whatever). So I don't believe anyone would want to use such a spell. And we see many times that **love is a powerful magic of its own**. You cannot *create* love, as we see with the love portions. We see other examples of the power of love - such as Lily's sacrifice. **Creating a spell to change someone's sexuality would go against the established canon that love is a powerful magic of its own.**

Comment: JKR isn't against date rape potions though.

Comment: @Valorum - Isn't she?

Comment: @Adamant - Love potions seem to be sold as novelties and are even described (in great detail) in the potion book for third year children. It's pretty clear that JKR saw them as whimsical rather than rapey until she'd had some time to think about it.

Comment: @Valorum - That last part, I think, is what I’m referring to. There’s a big difference between “Rowling didn’t think about the implications of many of her whimsical ideas imported from folklore” and “Rowling isn’t against date rape potions” (which makes it sound like she morally approves of them).